# spring cloud stream multi binder setup - remote source kafka with local destination kafka possible?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to consume messages from a remote kafka and produce output to a local kafka setup.
Additionally I don't want to 'pollute' the remote Kafka with kakfa streams specific technical topics (e.g. intermediate KTable stores).
I created an example app for demo purposes, however this doesn't work as expected - and I cannot say why.
Not working means: I don't really understand what's going on. Multiple consumers are being created but all to locahost, none seems to point to the remote kafka.

https://github.com/webermich/multibinder

https://github.com/webermich/multibinder/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.yaml

So my qustions are:

1. Is my general understanding correct that I can build something like I described above?
2. If the answer to 1) is true: Can anyone spot my mistakes?
3. I am really unsure about the  type: kstream of my bindings, too. I feel this is wrong.
4. Is there a link to a working example?